# Returning multiple rows from a function -- MySQL Database -- PDO

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I'm working on a blog site, and over the past few days I've been cleaning it up so it uses a lot more included functions rather than inline php. So far it's been really helpful.

Right now I'm trying to use a function to get all the blogposts in the database, which are stored like this:

[image]

Previously I was doing this right in my main blog.php file, which includes all the html. That looked like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $blogPost)
{
    $dateTime = date("j F, Y g:i a", (strtotime($blogPost['date_posted'])));

    echo "<div class='blog-main-preview'>";
    echo "<p class='blog-preview-title'>" . $blogPost['title'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p id='blog-preview-date'>" . $dateTime . "</p><br>";
    $post = $blogPost['post'];
    $post = strip_tags($post);
    $post = substr($post, 0, 200);
    echo "<p id='blog-preview-post'>" . $post . "...</p><br>";
    echo "<a href='blog-post.php?postid=" . $blogPost['id'] . "' id='read-more'><p>Read More</p></a><br>";
    echo "</div>";

}
```

This worked great but I was looking to move it to a function too. I realize I could just move the whole thing to a function, I was just hoping there was a solution where I didn't have to have any of the html in the function, and it could return something with which I could run the foreach loop in the main blog.php file. Can I do this?

Edit: So to clarify, what I'm looking for is to have my blog.php page look like:

```
$blogPosts = getBlogPosts($db);
foreach($blogPosts as $blogPost)
{
    $dateTime = date("j F, Y g:i a", (strtotime($blogPost['date_posted'])));

    echo "<div class='blog-main-preview'>";
    echo "<p class='blog-preview-title'>" . $blogPost['title'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p id='blog-preview-date'>" . $dateTime . "</p><br>";
    $post = $blogPost['post'];
    $post = strip_tags($post);
    $post = substr($post, 0, 200);
    echo "<p id='blog-preview-post'>" . $post . "...</p><br>";
    echo "<a href='blog-post.php?postid=" . $blogPost['id'] . "' id='read-more'><p>Read More</p></a><br>";
    echo "</div>";

}
```

And the functions file will contain the function which retrieves and returns the blogPosts.

Comment: don't know what you are asking

Comment: I need a function that will retrieve the blogposts and return it in such a way that I can iterate through them with a foreach loop.

Comment: which is exactly what you have above.

Comment: As I said in the question, I want the FUNCTION, to RETURN the results that can be iterated through from a DIFFERENT FILE, I don't want the function to iterate through them itself.

Comment: so wrap the db functions in a function and return the rows.

Comment: If I knew how to do that I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: that was suppose to be a question, not a statement, i forgot the ??????

Comment: Be nice to those helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
function getBlogPosts($db) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();

    // Get all results from the query as an array of associative arrays
    $rows = $sth->fetchAll();

    // Post-process results
    // Use `&` to get a reference to each row to prevent the default 
    // "copy on write" behavior of PHP's arrays from detaching our 
    // changes from the $rows array. Without this, the updated $row[X]
    // values would only be visible inside the foreach loop.
    foreach ($rows as &$row) {
      $row['date_posted'] = date("j F, Y g:i a", strtotime($row['date_posted']));
      $row['post'] = strip_tags($row['post']);
      $row['post'] = substr($row['post'], 0, 200);
    }

    return $rows;
}

$blogPosts = getBlogPosts($db);
foreach($blogPosts as $blogPost)
{ ?>

<div class="blog-main-preview">
  <p class="blog-preview-title"><?= htmlspecialchars($blogPost['title']) ?></p>
  <p id="blog-preview-date"><?= htmlspecialchars($blogPost['date_posted']) ?></p><br>
  <p id="blog-preview-post"><?= htmlspecialchars($blogPost['post']) ?>...</p><br>
  <a href="blog-post.php?postid=<?= urlencode($blogPost['id']) ?>" id="read-more"><p>Read More</p></a><br>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That did it! Turns out it won't work if "$blogPosts = getBlogPosts($db);" and the proceeding foreach loop are in different chunks of php, as long as they're in the same set of <?php ?> tags, it works. Odd, but that was my problem from the start. Thanks!

Do you think there's any way to get the:

    $dateTime = date("j F, Y g:i a", strtotime($blogPost['date_posted']));
    $post = strip_tags($blogPost['post']);
    $post = substr($post, 0, 200);

into the function as well?

Comment: @Chris the 1st and 3rd you can just do in the querry, the 2nd you will have to loop the data in the query.

Comment: It works! That's super cool and really makes the file a lot cleaner. I really appreciate al your help, but is there any chance you could explain how exactly the "&$row", works?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return `$stmt` from the function.

```
function getBlogPosts($db) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getBlogPosts($db){
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. :/ The Page still renders but no blog posts, so it seems like the foreach loop isn't retrieving results it needs.

Comment: `seems like` come on you can test that, then debug line by line with `echo`,`var_dump` and `print_r`